# wait for replication to stop before deleting the database

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a Couchbase Lite database on my app and want to delete the database by calling `database.delete()` method.  This needs to be closed first, but I don't know how to wait for the database to close:

Initialize and start:

```
      this.replicator = new Replicator(config);
      this.replicator.start();
```

Stop replication and database:

```
     replicator.stop();
     database.delete();
```

How do I wait for `replicator.stop()` to finish before calling the `delete` method?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation for stop](https://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.1/couchbase-lite-java/db001/com/couchbase/lite/Replicator.html#stop--):

> Stops a running replicator. This method returns immediately; when the replicator actually stops, the replicator will change its status's activity level to `kCBLStopped` and the replicator change notification will be notified accordingly.

So what you need to do is to add a change listener to your replicator and act on status change:

```
Replicator repl = new Replicator(config);
repl.addChangeListener(new ReplicatorChangeListener(){
   void changed(ReplicatorChange change){
      if (change.getStatus().getActivityLevel() ==  STOPPED){
          database.delete();
      }
   }

});
```

ReplicatorChangeListener documentation: [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.1/couchbase-lite-java/db001/com/couchbase/lite/ReplicatorChangeListener.html)